# Flying United from Kansas City to Dublin

Tags: air-travel, short-connections, united-airlines, ewr

Flying United from Kansas City to Dublin and have 41 minutes in Newark to make connection.Is 41 minutes enough time

Comment: First question, as always, is it one ticket or did you buy each leg seperately?

Answer (score 8):

> Is 41 minutes enough time

Assuming one ticket, the answer is maybe. (Two tickets = NO WAY)

United thinks it's doable: They sold you the ticket and are responsible for getting you to Dublin, even if you don't make the connection.

41 minutes is doable, but it's on the low side. The Gate closes typically 15 minutes before departure so you have 26 minutes to get off the plane, into the terminal, and to the new gate. Both of your flights are likely to be out of Terminal C, which is large. Walking distance can exceed half a mile (900m) so you should plan for this, especially if you have some mobility constraint or carrying a lot of stuff. If your Kansas flight arrives in Terminal A, you would have to take the shuttle, and you probaby won't make it.

> Is 41 minutes enough time

No connection is every guaranteed so it comes down to a risk assessment. What's the likelihood of making the connection and what's the consequences of missing it. I would put the likelihood at of missing it at about 10%-20%, with the main risk being a delay on the incoming flight. Even a smallish delay will jeopardize the connection. If you miss it, most likely United will put you up in a hotel for the night, you will fly the next day and arrive 24 hours later. If you have high status or a Polaris ticket, they may reroute you to get their earlier.

If you ok with that scenario, go for it. If there are significant problems with getting late to your destination, I would look for alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on one ticket, it should be now problem - the flights to Europe nearly always get out an hour late anyway, because they wait for connecting passengers.
If they don’t, the airline would be responsible for your missed connection, which is expensive for them, so they avoid it.

If you booked two separate tickets, your chances are very bad, mainly because you would need to pick up your luggage and recheck it - no way to do that in 41 minutes.

Comment: Your mileage may vary. United has been absolutely brutal with NOT waiting for anyone.  They closed a gate of the last red eye for six delay passengers while they were already in the terminal and within sight of the gate. (6 hotel rooms for the night). I once had my incoming delayed but was fast and got the gate with 2 minutes to spare. My boarding pass beeped red. Gate agent: "Oh, Mr. Hilmar, we didn't think you would make it, so we already gave away your seat".

Comment: @Hilmar it's important to note though that if the passenger doesn't make the connection, the airline will put the passenger on another plane if both legs were booked on the same ticket.

Comment: @phoog. Sure, but it's still a major inconvenience to spend the night in LA instead at home in Boston, just because you just can't run fast enough by 2 minutes.. I've seen United close the gate in front of woman going from LAX to Melbourne, Australia. The plane is still there, the jet bridge  is still docked, the cabin door is still open and the woman is sobbing. No mercy. Yes, you will get there eventually (or cancel) but it's painful and it doesn't even make sense financially for the airline.

Comment: @Hilmar that's absolutely true.  Some novice travelers here, however, seem to be under the mistaken impression that missing a connection means not making it to the destination, so it's worthwhile to keep the actual consequences in mind.